# Why LightGBM with 'objective': 'binary' donot return binary value 0 and 1 when call method predict?

Tags: python, classification, lightgbm

I create a binary classification model with LightGBM:

```
#Dataset
y_train = data_train['Label']
X_train = data_train.drop(['Label'], axis=1)

y_test = data_test['Label']
X_test = data_test.drop(['Label'], axis=1)

train_data = lgb.Dataset(data=X_train, label=y_train)
test_data = lgb.Dataset(data=X_test, label=y_test)

#Setting default parameters
params_wo_constraints = {
    'objective': 'binary',
    'boosting_type': 'gbdt',
    'metric': {'binary_logloss', 'auc'},
    'num_leaves': 32,
    'max_depth ': 5,
    'min_data_in_leaf': 100,
    'seed': 42,
    'bagging_seed': 42,
    'feature_fraction_seed': 42,
    'drop_seed': 42,
    'data_random_seed': 42
    }

#Model training
evals_result = {}
model_wo_constraints = lgb.train(
    params=params_wo_constraints,
    train_set=train_data,
    )
#Prediction
train_preds_wo_constraints = model_wo_constraints.predict(X_train)
test_preds_wo_constraints = model_wo_constraints.predict(X_test)
```

But the value of train_preds_wo_constraints is not 0 and 1:

```
>>> array([7.02862608e-02, 7.02498237e-01, 4.85224849e-01, ...,
       4.00079287e-04, 1.76385121e-01, 2.09733409e-01])
```

I have tried sklearn API and it works well

```
model = lgb.LGBMClassifier(learning_rate=0.09,max_depth=5,random_state=42)
model.fit(X_train,y_train,eval_set=[(X_test,y_test),(X_train,y_train)],
          verbose=20,eval_metric='logloss')

preds_wo_constraints = model.predict(X_train)
preds_wo_constraints

>>> array([0, 1, 1, ..., 0, 0, 0])
```

Could anyone can help me explain why and how to solve this problem?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! In the future, please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) when asking questions. Your post is not reproducible because it is missing `import` statements and the code used to create objects `data_train` and `data_test`, and because it is missing details like the version of Python and version of `lightgbm`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`train()` in the LightGBM Python package produces a `lightgbm.Booster` object.

For binary classification, `lightgbm.Booster.predict()` by default returns the predicted *probability* that the target is equal to 1.

Consider the following minimal, reproducible example using `lightgbm==3.3.2` and Python 3.8.12

```py
import lightgbm as lgb
from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs

X, y = make_blobs(
    n_samples=1000,
    n_features=5,
    centers=2,
    random_state=708
)
params = {
    "objective": "binary",
    "min_data_in_leaf": 5,
    "min_data_in_bin": 5,
    "seed": 708
}
bst = lgb.train(
    params=params,
    train_set=lgb.Dataset(data=X, label=y),
    num_boost_round=5
)

preds = bst.predict(X)
preds[:10]
```

```
array([0.29794759, 0.70205241, 0.70205241, 0.70205241, 0.29794759,
       0.29794759, 0.29794759, 0.29794759, 0.70205241, 0.29794759])
```

Those are probabilities that the value of the target is `1`.

In the scikit-learn interface from the `lightgbm` Python package, training produces an instance of `lightgbm.LGBMClassifier`.

For binary classification, `lightgbm.LGBMClassifier.predict()` returns the predicted class.

```py
clf = lgb.LGBMClassifier(**params)
clf.fit(X, y)
preds_sklearn = clf.predict(X)
preds_sklearn[:10]
```

```
array([0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0])
```

> explain why

`scikit-learn` requires that classifiers produce predicted classes from their `predict()` methods.

`scikit-learn` has very strict standards for writing custom estimators which are expected to be compatible with `scikit-learn`'s features. These are described in ["Developing scikit-learn estimators"](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/developers/develop.html). The "Glossary of Common Terms and API Elements" linked from that guide says that the `predict()` method for `scikit-learn` estimators must product predictions "in the same target space used in fitting", which for classification means "one of the values in the classifier’s `classes_` attribute" ([docs link](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/glossary.html#term-predict)).

`lightgbm.train()` is a lower-level interface whose goal is to provide performant, flexible control over LightGBM. It produces a `Booster` and `Booster.predict()` produces probabilities to allow users' code to choose what it wants to do with those probabilities (e.g. convert them to classes with a custom threshold, use them as sample weights for some post-processing code).

> how to solve this problem?

To convert predicted binary classification probabilities to predicted classes, compare those probabilities to a threshold.

```py
pred_class = (preds > 0.5).astype("int")
pred_class[:10]
```

```
array([0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0])
```